# Relation attribute linked to a node

Tags: neo4j

I want to have a schema where a `user` can give a vote to another `user`, for a specific `theme`.

I wonder the best way to doing this.

- The first way I think of is to make a relation between users with an attribute 'theme'.

```
(a)-[r:GIVE_VOTE {theme: "theme"}]->(b)
```

- The second one is to have a `Delegation` node, which have an "input" relation to the user who have given his vote, an 'output' relation to the user who received the vote, and another to a node "theme".

```
CREATE (:Person)-[:GIVE_VOTE]->(d:Delegation)-[:GIVE_VOTE]->(:Person)
CREATE (d)-[:FOR_THEME]->(:Theme)
```

For a huge number of nodes, have one string "theme" for each relation can be really heavy, but having a node `Delegation` with 3 relation, and a node "theme" too ... .

Maybe someone have a different way to do it, or an opinion on the two ways I can think of ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how we resolved an issue on "heavy" relationship for node (we call it densed node).

```
Instead of 
(a)-[r:GIVE_VOTE {theme: "theme"}]->(b),
We do this
(a)-[r:GIVE_VOTE_<theme>]->(b)
```

It is faster to query on a relationship with this setting rather than searching at the attribute r.theme.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I don't really like this method, because it store data in the "schema" of the database.but yes, it should be fast. I'll try it out.

Comment: it is a tested tweak and used in production